# Cycle triplets: A beats B beats C beats A. Minimum and maximum number of triplets for round-robin tournament of $2n+1$ teams? (contest question)

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

From the 2006 Canada National Olympiad:

> Consider a round-robin tournament with $2n + 1$ teams, where each team plays
>   each other team exactly once. We say that three teams $X, Y\text{ and }Z$, form a *cycle triplet* if X beats Y , Y beats Z and Z beats X. There are no ties.
>
> a. Determine the minimum number of cycle triplets possible.
>
> b. Determine the maximum number of cycle triplets possible.

*I need help with the second part.*

---

a. It is possible to have no cycle triplets.

Consider $G$ as a directed graph where there is an edge from $A$ to $B$ if $A$ beats $B$ (symbolised as $\succ$ since it may be non-transitive). We are looking for 3-cycles in the graph.

Number the teams $T_1,T_2,\dots,T_{2n+1}$ and define a simple rule for victory:

$T_i \succ T_j \iff i>j,\text{ for all }i,j|1\le i,j\le2n+1\tag{1}$

This rule covers all possible games between teams.

Now it is clear that node $T_{2n+1}$ has only outbound edges, as it beats all others. Then it cannot possibly be a member of a cycle triplet, so the number of cycle triplets will not be changed by removing $T_{2n+1}$ and all its outbound edges to obtain graph $G'$.

In $G'$, node $T_{2n}$ has only outbound edges, so it cannot possibly be a member of a cycle triplet. Therefore, $T_{2n}$ and all its outbound edges can be removed from $G'$ to form $G''$, and so on. So, by induction (base case an edge or single node), $G$ contains no cycle triplets.

(Or you could consider the adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$ where $A_{ij}=\cases{1, i>j \\ 0, \text{otherwise}}$ and show that it is lower triangular with zeroes on the diagonal, and so $\mathbf{A}^m=\mathbf{0},\:\forall m\ge2$, i.e. there are no m-cycles.)

---

b. I am not sure what the maximum is.

Let $C(n)$ be the maximum number of cyclic triangles in tournament of $2n+1$ teams.

For $n=1$ (3 teams): $C(1) = 1$

For $n=2$ (5 teams): $C(2) \ge 4$ through experimentation

I suspect that $C(n) = n^2$ but cannot prove.

Comment: https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cmb/v8/cmb1965v08.0491-0498.pdf

Comment: @joriki - Thanks for the article. Those were definitely the days before $\LaTeX$ typesetting of equations!